# completely remove phpmyadmin centos

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, rhel6, phpmyadmin

I removed phpmyadmin on my CentOS server by typing

```
yum erase phpmyadmin
```

Then I checked if it's still in the server by `locate` and it displayed this:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
/usr/share/phpmyadmin
/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin-2.11.11.3
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/Documentation.html
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/browse_foreigners.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/calendar.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/changelog.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/chk_rel.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.sample.inc.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/contrib
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_create.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_datadict.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_export.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_import.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_operations.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_printview.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_qbe.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_search.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_sql.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/db_structure.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/docs.css
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/error.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/export.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/favicon.ico
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/import.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/js
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/lang
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/license.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/main.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/navigation.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pdf_pages.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pdf_schema.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpinfo.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_common.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_display_field.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_general.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_help.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_pdf.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_relation_new.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_relation_upd.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/pmd_save_pos.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/print.css
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/querywindow.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/readme.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/scripts
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_binlog.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_collations.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_databases.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_engines.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_export.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_import.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_privileges.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_processlist.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_sql.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_status.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/server_variables.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/show_config_errors.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/sql.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_addfield.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_alter.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_change.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_create.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_export.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_import.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_indexes.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_move_copy.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_operations.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_printview.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_relation.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_replace.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_row_action.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_select.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_sql.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/tbl_structure.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/transformation_overview.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/transformation_wrapper.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/translators.html
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/user_password.php
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/view_create.php
/var/lib/yum/yumdb/p/2c0c9042434bd52b58095c7d7d79477a9d5c45a3-phpmyadmin-2.11.11.3-2.el6.rf-noarch
```

Do I have to manually remove these? The reason is I want to fresh install it as something is messed up.

Answer (score 5):

You do realise that [`locate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate) looks at a database cache with filenames (created nightly/manually with the `updatedb` command) and not at your live file system.

`locate` does not reflect the actual state of your system.

You might want to use `ls` to look at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` instead...

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to CentOS so I'm confused why they still appear. A config.inc.php.rpmsave is still there. Will deleting it "completely remove" phpmyadmin in my system?

Comment: Well behaved RPM packages can detect if you customised any configuration files from  what was included in the package and will preserve those for you with the `.rpmsave` extension (on upgrade and when you remove the RPM package). You can safely delete those, but they don't conflict with a reinstall of the package either.

Comment: Also you can manually run `updatedb` to refresh your locate database.